# invalid write size: memset

Tags: c, valgrind, memcheck

```
void readdat (int c, char **v) {

char *dc;
char *pdc;

dc = malloc((line+1) * sizeof(char));
memset(dc, 0, (line+1) * sizeof(char));

FILE *datfile;
datfile = fopen(v[3], "r");

while(fgets(dc, line, datfile) != NULL) {
 pdc = strtok(dc, "\t");
 countcDat = 0;
 while(pdc != NULL) {
  ++countcDat;
  pdc = strtok(NULL, "\t");
 }
 ++countrDat;
}

dat = malloc(countrDat * sizeof(char**));
memset(dat, 0, countrDat * sizeof(char**));

for(i=0;i<countrDat;++i) {
 dat[i] = malloc(countcDat * sizeof(char*));
 memset(dat[i], 0, countcDat * sizeof(char*));
}

for(i=0;i<countrDat;++i) {
 for(j=0;j<countcDat;++j) {
  dat[i][j] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
  memset(dat[i][j], 0, 20 * sizeof(char)); ###
 }
}

rewind(datfile);

countrDat = 0;
countcDat = 0;

while(fgets(dc, line, datfile) != NULL) {
 pdc = strtok(dc, "\t");
countcDat = 0;
while(pdc != NULL) {
 sscanf(pdc, "%s", dat[countrDat][countcDat]);
 ++countcDat;
 pdc = strtok(NULL, "\t");
}
++countrDat;
}

for(i=0;i<countrDat;++i) {
 for(j=0;j<countcDat;++j) {
  printf("%s\t", dat[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}

fclose(datfile);
free(dc);
for(i=0;i<countrDat;++i) {
 for(j=0;j<countcDat;++j) {
  free(dat[i][j]);
 }
}
for(i=0;i<countrDat;++i) {
 free(dat[i]);
}
free(dat);
}
```

valgrind says invalid write of size 1 at memset ("###" - marked line). Please help figure out what is wrong here. Following "Address 0x0 is not stack'd, nor malloc'd nor free'd" of valgrind output I could rule out strtok as being responsible. It probably is obvious...

Comment: Another good example why to **always** check the result of system calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Please help figure out what is wrong here. Following "Address 0x0 is not stack'd, nor malloc'd nor free'd"

Well, the address came from `malloc`, and `malloc` could fail. When it does fail, it returns `NULL`, which explains the `0x0` address.

The reason `malloc` fails is likely that you are leaking memory elsewhere.

Comment: @alk could you please explain?

Comment: I did figure that out in the end. I wanted to make sure if this function by itself has a serious error that I overlooked.